# Symfony2 not load Type when createForm

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I want createForm but symfony not load my top form:

This is my code:

in my frontend.html.twig:

```
{% render "NewsletterBundle:Default:form" %}
```

in NewsletterBundle/Form/NewsletterUserType.php:

```php
<?php

namespace LoPati\NewsletterBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation\Service;
use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation\Tag;

/**
 * @Service("lopati.form.newsletter_user")
 * @Tag("form.type", attributes = { "alias" = "mp_newsletter_user" })
 */
class NewsletterUserType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
                ->add('email')
        ;
    }


    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'LoPati\NewsletterBundle\Entity\NewsletterUser'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'mp_newsletter_user';
    }

}
```

In NewsletterBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php:

```php
<?php

namespace LoPati\NewsletterBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;

use LoPati\NewsletterBundle\Entity\NewsletterUser;

class DefaultController extends Controller 
{

    /**
     * @Template()
     */
    public function formAction(Request $request)
    {
        $newsletterUser = new NewsletterUser();

       $form = $this->createForm('mp_newsletter_user', $newsletterUser);

        return array('form' => $form->createView());
    }

}
```

And in NewsletterBundle/Resources/views/Default/form.html.twig

```
<form action="" method="post" class="newsletter">
    {{ form_widget(form.email) }}
    {{ form_widget(form._token) }}    
    <button type="submit">newsletter</button>
</form>
```

This is the error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Could not load type "mp_newsletter_user"")

When is the problem?

Thanks

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've defined your form as a service, so, change your create form to:

```
 // $form = $this->createForm('mp_newsletter_user', $newsletterUser);
 $form = $this->createForm($this->get('mp_newsletter_user'), $newsletterUser); // you need use $this->get to get a service
```

This also should work:

```
 $this->createForm(new \LoPati\NewsletterBundle\Form\NewsletterUserType(), $newsletterUser);
```

Comment: I changed it but I obtained this error: Fatal error: Class 'LoPati\NewsletterBundle\Controller\NewsletterUserType' not found in

Comment: I didn't notice that you've defined your form as a service, so I've editet my answer